# StringBuilder and Radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I am using stringbuilder to create a radiobuttonlist dynamically for a survey I am working on. The code validates fine but will not render in HTML.

Is this because I am not supposed to use stringbuilder to generate asp web controls?

code here:

```
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:RadioButtonList ID='" + qnumber + "' runat='server' RepeatDirection='Horizontal' RepeatLayout='flow' CssClass='answers'>"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:ListItem Text='Strongly Agree' Value='1'></asp:ListItem>"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:ListItem Text='Agree' Value = '2' ></ asp:ListItem>"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:ListItem Text='Disagree' Value='3'></asp:ListItem>"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:ListItem Text='Strongly Disagree' Value='4'></asp:ListItem>"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<asp:ListItem Text='Not Applicable' Value='5'></asp:ListItem></asp:RadioButtonList><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat='server' ID='" + qnumber + "v"+ "' ControlToValidate='ID='" + qnumber + "' ErrorMessage='please answer the question' CssClass='warning' />"));
```

Comment: Are you writing some sort of template generation tool like [T4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers/)? Otherwise not clear how you expect ASP.Net to compile resulting string produced by your code.

Comment: Well, what are you doing with the stringbuilder results?

Comment: nothing basically. the rest of the stringbuilder html renders.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to this question, but `StringBuilder` has a method [`AppendFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat(v=vs.110).aspx) that does exactly what `Append(string.Format(` does. Also, format is supposed to be used so that you don't have to concatenate strings like your first line...

Comment: Cheers Mike. I'm new to asp, always learning!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, you can't force your code behind to generate asp.Net code, those must be placed inside your aspx page. Asp.Net transform asp tags in html tags and listen to them on code behind, that's why you can't send asp tags to your view, the view is already processed by asp.net when code behind code is running.

Your best bet is to send pure HTML content to your page and use another way to read its contents. If you're in a hurry, I suggest you use Javascript to fill a HiddenField just before postbacking your form.

Here's an example on how your StringBuilder should look like:

```
sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" />Strongly Agree"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" />Agree"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="3" />Disagree"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="4" />Strongly Disagree"));
sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="5" />Not Applicable"));
```

Then you just use below code on javascript to set the value to a HiddenField:

```
$('#<%= youHiddenFieldId.ClientID %>').val($("input:radio[name='answer']:checked").val());
```

Now you just need to call `youHiddenFieldId.Value` on code behind to get the value of the selected checkbox.

Comment: Thanks lucas. Basically a data table populates the questions for the survey and the string builder creates the answers using for (....) The questions render fine just need a way to generate the answers dynamically.

Comment: I just provided some code example on my answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Yes. Place `sb.Append(string.Format("<input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" />Strongly Agree"));` inside the desired loop. Be sure to change the name of the radios to something like `name="answer_" + qnumber`.